# Python3 - How to detect mouse clicked on the image or not in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, mouse

I am making a game and i want to get image position which i have placed in center i tried `image.get_rect()` but it returned me the image rectangle size

My Code as follows:

```
import pygame
import random # for random line color
import pygame.mouse

# Random color script
a = random.randrange(1,255,1)
b = random.randrange(1,255,1)
c = random.randrange(1,255,1)
linecolor = a, b, c
#a bunch of variables
bgcolor = 0, 0, 0
x = y = 0
LEFT = 1
running = 1
s = 0

h, w = 640, 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((h, w))
# defining image
image = pygame.image.load( "DK.bmp" )
imagePosition = image.get_rect()
imagePosition.bottom = 200
imagePosition.left = 300
screen.blit( image, imagePosition )

pygame.mixer.init()
shot = pygame.mixer.Sound("shot.wav")
         

while running:
     event = pygame.event.poll()
     pygame.display.init()
     # font stuff
     pygame.font.init()
     fontDefault = pygame.font.Font( None, 48 )
     fontScoot = pygame.font.Font("scootchover-sans.ttf",24)
     
     pygame.event.pump()
     pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
     
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          running = 0
     elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
          x, y = event.pos
     elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
          s = s + 1 # number of shots fired
          shot.play()
          x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

          if image.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
               print('clicked on image')

     
     # score board color variables and "if" statements:
     s1 = 66
     s2 = 66
     s3 = 66
     if s > 99:
          s1 = 0
          s2 = 120
          s3 = 0
     if s > 199:
          s1 = 255
          s2 = 120
          s3 = 0
     if s  > 299:
          s1 = 187
          s2 = 0
          s3 = 0
     if s > 399:
          s1 = 255
          s2 = 255
          s3 = 0
     if s > 499:
          s1 = 0
          s2 = 0
          s3 = 255
     if s > 599:
          s1 = 0
          s2 = 255
          s3 = 0
     if s > 699:
          s1 = 128
          s2 = 255
          s3 = 255
     if s > 799:
          s1 = 64
          s2 = 128
          s3 = 128
     if s > 899:
          s1 = 255
          s2 = 255
          s3 = 255
     if s > 999:
          # score board
          s1 = random.randrange(1,255,1)
          s2 = random.randrange(1,255,1)
          s3 = random.randrange(1,255,1)
          # aimer
          a = random.randrange(1,255,1)
          b = random.randrange(1,255,1)
          c = random.randrange(1,255,1)
          linecolor = a, b, c
          ya = random.randrange(1,6,1)
          if ya == 1:
               image = pygame.image.load( "ya.bmp" )
          if ya == 2:
               image = pygame.image.load( "ya2.bmp" )
          if ya == 3:
               image = pygame.image.load( "ya3.bmp" )
          if ya == 4:
               image = pygame.image.load( "ya4.bmp" )
          if ya == 5:
               image = pygame.image.load( "ya5.bmp" )
          if ya == 6:
               image = pygame.image.load( "ya6.bmp" )
     score = fontScoot.render( "Score: " + str(s),1, (s1,s2,s3))
     if s > 999:
          score = fontScoot.render( "OMG!! YOU SCORE IS " + str(s),1, (s1,s2,s3))
     if s > 1999:
          score = fontScoot.render( "HOLY F*CKING SH*T!! YOU SCORE IS " + str(s),1, (s1,s2,s3))

     pygame.display.set_caption("Shooter")

     screen.blit( score, (500,100) )
     screen.fill(bgcolor)
     screen.blit( image, imagePosition )
     pygame.draw.line(screen, linecolor, (x, 0), (x, 399))
     pygame.draw.line(screen, linecolor, (0, y), (639, y))
     screen.blit( score, (100,100) )
     pygame.display.flip()
```

My Code includes some images and all so i have uploaded whole images and all on this [link](https://www.github.com/theindianhacker/shooter)
I Am using python 3.8 & I am on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).

You have already set the image rectangle to `imagePosition`. Use `imagePosition` rather than `image.get_rect()`:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = 0
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            x, y = event.pos
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
            s = s + 1 # number of shots fired
            shot.play()
            if imagePosition.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print('clicked on image')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here try this

```
def on_click(event=None):
    # `command=` calls function without argument
    # `bind` calls function with one argument
    print("image clicked")
```

Comment: PyGame has no `on_click` event. Don't confuse [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) with [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)